# Manhwa/manga where the mc starts off in a cave and a window appears telling him to witness the end?

Tags: story-identification, manga, martial-arts

I can't remember if the MC woke up in the cave on the stone bed , was teleported there or if he died and was temporarily reincarnated there. However the MC get a notification telling him to witness the end and believing it wants him to witness the end of the world the MC sets out to survive for as long as possible. The cave only had the stone bed the MC was lying on if that rings any bells. Eventually the MC becomes an extremely powerful and feared martial master and returns to earth. I also remember there being a female guild master who went through a similar situation as multiple people had that same experience.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?